# Why do we want to maximize AUC in classification problems?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, mathematical-optimization

I wonder why is our objective is to maximize AUC when maximizing accuracy yields the same?

I think that along with the primary goal to maximize accuracy, AUC will automatically be large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess we use AUC because it explains how well our method is able to separate the data independently of a threshold.
For some applications, we don't want to have false positive or negative. And when we use accuracy, we already make an a priori on the best threshold to separate the data regardless of the specificity and sensitivity. 
.

Answer (score 3):

In binary classification, accuracy is a performance metric of a single model for a certain threshold and the AUC (Area under ROC curve) is a performance metric of a series of models for a series of thresholds.

Thanks to this question, I have learnt quite a bit on AUC and accuracy comparisons. I don't think that there's a correlation between the two and I think this is still an open problem. At the end of this answer, I've added some links like [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90659/why-is-auc-higher-for-a-classifier-that-is-less-accurate-than-for-one-that-is-mo) that I think would be useful.

---

**One scenario where accuracy fails:**

---

**Example Problem**

Let's consider a binary classification problem where you evaluate the performance of your model on a data set of **100** samples (**98** of class `0` and **2** of class `1`).

Take out your sophisticated machine learning model and replace the whole thing with a dumb system that always outputs `0` for whatever the input it receives.
What is the accuracy now?

```
Accuracy = Correct predictions/Total predictions = 98/100 = 0.98
```

We got a stunning 98% accuracy on the *"Always `0`"* system.

Now you convert your system to a cancer diagnosis system and start predicting (`0` - No cancer, `1` - Cancer) on a set of patients. Assuming there will be a few cases that corresponds to class `1`, you will still achieve a high accuracy.

Despite having a high accuracy, what is the point of the system if it fails to do well on the class `1` (Identifying patients with cancer)?

---

This observation suggests that accuracy is not a good evaluation metric for *every* type of machine learning problems. The above is known as an imbalanced class problem and there are enough practical problems of this nature.

---

As for the comparison of accuracy and AUC, here are some links I think would be useful,

1. [An introduction to ROC analysis](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1159475)
2. [Area under curve of ROC vs. overall accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68893/area-under-curve-of-roc-vs-overall-accuracy)
3. [Why is AUC higher for a classifier that is less accurate than for one that is more accurate?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90659/why-is-auc-higher-for-a-classifier-that-is-less-accurate-than-for-one-that-is-mo)
4. [What does AUC stand for and what is it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it)
5. [Understanding ROC curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/understanding-roc-curve/105577)
6. [ROC vs. Accuracy vs. AROC](http://hunch.net/?p=21)

Comment: Am I correct if I say -"Maximization of AUC is considered when comparing different classification models on same problem and it is not logical to maximize AUC in one particular classification model" ?

Comment: Having a high AUC for a single model does make sense. Recall that the optimal ROC curve we could get is the step function with the step at False Positive Rate=0. What does that -or even a sub-optimal curve (that has AUC>0.5)- imply? You would have high True Positve Rates even for the thresholds that would result in higher False Positve Rates, which is good.